# anyof json schema is not working on IE React JSON Schema

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema

We have react application, in which we have defined a JSON Schema, we have five input fields, out of which, three are required and two are optional, I want user to input atleast one out of two optional fields, hence I am using anyof keyword from JSON schema, but its not working on IE.
Below is the my code.

```
 'type': 'object',
        'appName': 'dlp',
        'formName': 'CSPV', 
        "anyOf": [
           {"required": ["address"]},
           {"required": ["PHONE"]}
        ],
        'required': [
          'email'
        ],
```

Some how its not working on IE, any alternative solution for this, any help would be appreciated. I am using React JSON Schema.

Comment: Withoug knowing which JSON Schema library you're using, I'm not sure anyone is going to be able to help you. Your best bet on this is to file a issue on the libraries issue system. IE may not even be supported.

Comment: I am using React JSON Schema.

Comment: It looks like the library npm `react-json-schema` has "a JSON schema" (small s) as opposed to uses JSON Schema the specification.

Comment: is there any error throwing, also kindly add the repo of the library i found react json schema and react json schema form , which one you are using kindly add that repo url. Also are you using any polyfill so may be the library is using some methods which are not supported by IE like includes doesn't support in IE we need to use indexOf so like that if you add polyfill it will do the job

Comment: I am using react json schema form, can you show some example of polyfill.